# Google vision api annotateImage returns empty

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-vision

I am trying to do multiple type detection of a single image with google vision api. However it returns empty response. If I do single type using specific method it works e.g. `labelDetection` detect labels.

What am I doing wrong with `await client.annotateImage(request);`? I tried passing `content` as well as defining `filename` in both scenarios it fails

```
    const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({ fallback: true, auth })
 
    const content = await readFileSync(imagePath, 'base64');

    const image = {
      source: {
        // Try filename / path
        filename: path.join(__dirname, '..', imagePath)
      },
      // Try base64
      content
    }
    const features = [
      {type: 'FACE_DETECTION'},
      {type: 'LABEL_DETECTION'},
      {type: 'SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION'},
    ]
    const request = {
      image,
      features,
    };
    const labelResults = await client.labelDetection(imagePath);
    console.log(labelResults)
// RESPONSE
[
  AnnotateImageResponse {
    faceAnnotations: [],
    landmarkAnnotations: [],
    logoAnnotations: [],
    labelAnnotations: [
      [EntityAnnotation],
      [EntityAnnotation],
      [EntityAnnotation],
      [EntityAnnotation],
      [EntityAnnotation],
      [EntityAnnotation],
      [EntityAnnotation],
      [EntityAnnotation],
      [EntityAnnotation],
      [EntityAnnotation]
    ],
    localizedObjectAnnotations: [],
    textAnnotations: []
  }
]

    const result = await client.annotateImage(request);
    console.log(result)

// RESPONSE 
[
  AnnotateImageResponse {
    faceAnnotations: [],
    landmarkAnnotations: [],
    logoAnnotations: [],
    labelAnnotations: [],
    localizedObjectAnnotations: [],
    textAnnotations: []
  }
]
```

Comment: Don't read a file synchronously and then `await` the result. Use `const data = await fs.promises.readFile(path)`

Comment: @AluanHaddad that's not it... I tried that as well also based on examples from here https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/blob/master/test/helpers.test.ts

Comment: That's not the cause of your issue but is incorrect nevertheless